# How to display icon in messagebox in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, messagebox

I am trying to create an icon in a message box from the image "/newicon.png" in my resources.qrc file. However the image does not appear when I create the messagebox.

What could the problem be with my code below?

```
void MainWindow::aboutClicked(){
    QMessageBox messageBox;
    messagebox.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/newicon.png"));
    messageBox.setText("hello this is the message box");
    messageBox.setWindowTitle("About");
    messageBox.exec();
}
```

Edit:
More info regarding resources.qrc file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/.">
        <file>button.png</file>
        <file>newicon.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your prefix from

```
<qresource prefix="/.">
```

to

```
<qresource prefix="/">
```

Comment: Thanks, I mistakenly included the full stop because the tutorial I was reading placed "/" at the end of the sentence!